# instabug IBGInvocationEventTwoFingersSwipeLeft not work

Tags: java, android, instabug

Sorry for my english. I try use service [instabug](https://instabug.com), they i try use `IBGInvocationEventTwoFingersSwipeLeft` but this is not successful. I try somthing like this:

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
        Instabug.initialize(getApplication(), "mykey");
        Instabug.getInstance().setInvocationEvent(Instabug.IBGInvocationEvent.IBGInvocationEventTwoFingersSwipeLeft);
```

and like this

```
  ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    Instabug.initialize(getApplication(), "mykey").setInvocationEvent(Instabug.IBGInvocationEvent.IBGInvocationEventTwoFingersSwipeLeft);
```

but my method dont work(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you haven't finished the [SDK integration](https://instabug.com/sdk-integration#android) steps. Specifically, if your Activity classes don't extend Instabug activities.